# Stripe for collecting a house's split rent amounts from housemates, and, to on-send rent only once all have paid their share?

Tags: stripe-payments

I saw this on Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web, and, whilst it's a different use case, it's had me wondering whether Stripe:

- Be used to collect (i.e. by debiting a bank account or taking it via CC) the contributing share of each of a house's occupants' rental payments, and, once the full amount has been received, to either on-send the total rent owing to the landlord's account, or even better, to enable the amount to be debited by the landlord

I'm new to coding and not sure if this is a good idea but any advice/ thoughts would be an immense help here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does seem like it would be technically possible. You'd use Connect payments like in your guide and your 'customers' are the tenants and the 'connected account' who receives the funds is the landlord.

Comment: I see! For this however, is it possible for me to have it function so that the landlord can only be sent or debit the amount owed to them if/when all of the renters in the household have paid their share? I would also want to have a cut that's provided to our company (we furnish the property for the renters)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible!

I have integrated this type of use case in my website.

When each housemate pay their contribution amount then by use of webhooks, you will be notified that payment is completed.

Keep record of each payment by each housemate and when sum of all payments of all housemates is same as house rent then transfer the amount to the house owner.

Comment: Sounds great thanks for this. With this said, we have certain owners that need to be able to debit the amount in rent from an account. Would this be possible somehow too? I'm thinking perhaps we need to set up bank accounts for each renter to transfer there sums to for the owner to debit hmm

Comment: That will also be possible.

Comment: Would you be ok to let me know how you might approach setting that up? Thanks a ton 